# Creating metadata with CMD?

Tags: cmd

In a security+ class we were shown how to inject exes and etc into a file using CMD line. The command was along the lines of:

```
CMD > Notepad.exe "file.exe:otherfile.exe"
```

In his explanation it added Notepad to file.exe by the name of otherfile.exe.

The problem with this is that he claims it is injecting a file directly into that file, but he showed us how the file size doesn't change but total NTFS file system size changes.

I believe he is talking about generic metadata and not changing the file in any way. Can someone please clarify or give me a reference to the command he is talking about or a good explanation?

Comment: Please if you downvote give a reason, as this is a fairly legitimate question as to how a command works.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, which means it's not really appropriate here. You can find info on what you're looking for at MSDN in [How to Use NTFS Alternate File Streams](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/105763). The term "Alternate File Stream" should give you something useful to Google for more details as well (it's how I located the MSDN article).

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for. I tried googling probably 20 different terms to figure out how it would be called as all he called it was ADS.

Comment: Yep. I searched for Alternate File Streams; the article was actually "How to Use NTFS Alternate DATA Streams", not "File Streams". :-)

Comment: If you're familiar can you confirm if the AltDS is located on the file, or is it moved to a system folder? I write scripts for my work and would be nice to add a descriptive AltDS to the file but need it to move across networks. When I last looked into metadata it didn't seem to be attached to the file and why it was on XP but removed on Vista and forward.

Comment: As long as the file stays within Windows the streams will stay attached. But email, zips, etc don't understand streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it may answer a few of your questions:

```
md test
cd test
dir
echo this is my file>file.txt
dir
echo alternative data stream>file.txt:hidden
dir
dir /r
del file.txt
dir /r
```